# "Beyond over" for long distances

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

Can we use "**beyond over**" for long distances? Will it be idiomatic and beautiful English?

- My home is beyond over that mountain.
- The path leads beyond over the hills and far into the dark moore.

I want to say that something is over something and beyond *(beyond [over something])*.

Comment: Why do want to use "over"?

Comment: @Cardinal Because I think I want to precisely state that something is beyond something over which we have to render. Not **through**, but really **over**.

Comment: **beyond** does not modify **over**.  *My house lies beyond, over the mountains.*  **beyond** =  in the distance ahead relative to some place (whether the place is here, or some other locus referred to).

Comment: *My house lies beyond that mountain.*  When you cross over the mountain, my house will lie beyond.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP writes: **I want to say that something is over something and beyond (beyond [over something]). ... I want to precisely state that something is beyond something over which we have to [go].**

The problem OP has created for himself here arises from the way he is (mis)using the preposition **over**.

If I say

> My house lies over that hill.

of course I don't mean that my house is up on a cloud floating in the air above the hill; I mean that my house is *located* on the other side of that hill (other side, relative to our vantage point here).

If I say

> My house lies beyond that hill.

I mean that my house is *located* on the other side of that hill as seen from our vantage point here.

The two sentences are more or less synonymous.

If you want to use **over** to refer not to *location* but to the *motion* required to get there (ascending and descending), the destination would not be the subject. The traveler would be the subject:

> To reach my house, **you** must *go over* that hill. My house lies beyond.

In most practical contexts there's no need to tell the listener they must ascend and descend a hill to reach the far side, but perhaps OP has a video game in mind, where tunneling is sometimes an option, but not in this particular case.

Comment: My idea is that "beyond over" is just indecision on the proper preposition to use, and midsentence "over" is used instead, or perhaps the original sentence is extended for clarification.  "My house is beyond.. over that hill."

Comment: Let's not introduce dramatic contextual explanations for what "beyond over" might mean and focus on the idea OP is trying to convey.

Comment: OP was asking if "beyond over" is quote "idiomatic and beautiful English", so I think dramatic contextual explanations are entirely welcome here.

Comment: But if you read the rest of the comments, you will see that OP has stated a specific goal, which I have made clear at the top of my answer.

Comment: Don't misunderstand me, my comment wasn't a critique on your answer.  I was merely pointing out that "beyond over" may be heard together in entirely coincidental circumstances.

Comment: OK. But I didn't want to go down that particular rabbit hole, as it is not really germane to the core question.

Comment: What about "**over and beyond**" to show that you have to go over a mountain and then the house is somewhere beyond? I've heard phrases like *(something like)* "**The passageway is somewhere far through there**"

Comment: *My house lies **over and beyond** that mountain* is good.  *The pot of gold lies through and beyond that passageway.*

Comment: I understood you to mean that you wanted to say "precisely" and unambiguously that skirting the mountains was not an option, and that going under the mountain was not an option, that is, that we must **go over** the mountain.

Answer (score 2):

What meaning do you want to convey. If you just want to say these places are a bit far away, it will sound better as "over beyond". Using "over" sounds more folksy than poetic, at least to me.

If you want to say that the home is even farther away than "over the mountain" you could say it's "beyond the other side of that mountain", or that that the path leads "beyond the far side of the hills".

Comment: Reordering the prepositions will make it more idiomatic? So not "**beyond over the mountain**" but "**over beyond the mountain**"? Doesn't it make more sense to conjoin **over** and **the mountain** and to have **beyond** apply to this whole union instead of what you recommend?

Comment: @SovereignSun, "over beyond" would be using "over" in an informal way to indicate a moderate distance. The same way we use it in "over there" or "over in Clarkesville".

Comment: @SovereignSun in my opinion "over beyond" is somewhat *colloquial* and (as Tᴚoɯɐuo mentions in his comment) redundant -- but still something native speakers do say to emphasize distance.  Although now that I think of it, I may be confusing this with "over **yonder**", a related colloquialism.

Comment: @Andrew Oh, my. I'm already loving this word "**yonder**".